# Angular open a pdf in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my angular 12 application I want to "view" a pdf file in a new chrome tab. The file is saved locally in the application and we need a functionality where user can view the pdf in a new tab ( not just download ). I am handling this in HTML like this:

```
<a [href]="privacyLinks.pdfLink" (click)="previewPdf(privacyLinks.pdfLink)"  class="policy-control-link"
target="_blank"><img [src]="privacyLinks.viewSvg" alt="">{{
privacyLinks.viewLabel }}
```

This is downloading the file instead of opening it a new tab. I tried creating a (click) function and use window.open(pdfFile,'_blank') but it still does the same thing.
How do I open the .pdf in a new Chrome tab?

Comment: replicate the issue in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7mqhry?)

Comment: Did you try to add the mime type? `<a [href]="privacyLinks.pdfLink" (click)="previewPdf(privacyLinks.pdfLink)"  class="policy-control-link"
target="_blank" type="application/pdf">`

Comment: type="application/pdf" does not help

Answer (score 0):

Function that retrieves pdf and opens in new tab. Works with Chrome

```
  onCreateInvoice(params: Params) {
     this.http.post(this.path, params, { responseType: 'blob' })
       .subscribe(somePdf => {
          window.open(URL.createObjectURL(somePdf), 'new');
       })
  }
```

Comment: what is params here?

Comment: `params` are just for illustration here. Construct your http request as needed.

Comment: thanks for your help. my pdf is saved locally so how do adapt window.open(URL.createObjectURL(somePdf), 'new'); to my needs. I believe somePdf is the .pdf file. What is URL ?

Comment: I think there is a Chrome setting that manages this. Is there any way to change/by-pass this using angular code. My chrome settings are managed by admin and I cannot change it. Here are the settings:
  1. In your google chrome settings, search “site settings” and click on the result that says “site settings”. 
2. Scroll down to “Additional Content Settings” and click on it so a menu drops down
3. Click PDF documents .
4. For the setting labelled “download pdf files instead of automatically opening them in chrome” Toggle the switch so the ball is to the left, turning it off.

Comment: You can't change Chrome settings programmatically, AFAIK. If admin prohibits you from opening PDF documents in Chrome, that there is no way to do so.
URL is just a browser API object that represents some network location. But it's possible to create a URL from downloaded data blob and open in browser window. [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)